# How to count all unique values in a data.frame

Tags: r, count, dataframe, token, plyr

I've got a data frame with diagnoses as variables and patients as observations. It's 32 variables and 5000 observations.

Please look at this example.

It is my goal to count and sum up all the diagnoses in the data frame

```
set.seed(1)
Data <- data.frame(id = seq(1, 10), 
Diag1 = sample(c("A123", "B123", "C123"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
Diag2 = sample(c("D123", "E123", "F123"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
Diag3 = sample(c("G123", "H123", "I123"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
Diag4 = sample(c("A123", "B123", "C123"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
Diag5 = sample(c("J123", "K123", "L123"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
Diag6 = sample(c("M123", "N123", "O123"), 10, replace = TRUE), 
Diag7 = sample(c("P123", "Q123", "R123"), 10, replace = TRUE))
Data
class(Data)
mode(Data)
```

I know how to do it for one column using the plyr package

```
NoDiag1 <- count(Data, "Diag1")
```

How can I do this for the whole data frame instead of one variable?

If this is not possible, how can I add up column 1-7 to one column so that I can use the count function for this "merged" column?

Comment: Do you mean to count all characters or only non-numeric characters? (So is `"AB12"` 2 or 4?)

Comment: Why not simply `count(Data[,-1])`?

Comment: Hi there. I want to know how many "AB123"s there are in the whole data frame. You might exchange "AB123" with "dog" and "B123" with cat. Then I would like to know how often the words "dog" and "cat" appear in the data frame.

Comment: The request to count "characters" was confusing. You should ask for "unique values" or "tokens" or "diagnoses" or somesuch. There are 5 characters in "AB123".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an approach without *plyr* using `table`:

```
## Data[,-1] is the complete data.frame without the "id" column
table(unlist(Data[,-1]))

# A123 B123 C123 D123 E123 F123 G123 H123 I123 J123 K123 L123 M123 N123 O123 P123 Q123 R123 
#    5    8    7    2    3    5    4    4    2    1    4    5    4    5    1    4    3    3
```